# Error Creating new file stream

Tags: file, c#-4.0, filestream

This is the following code snippet to find a image from a folder image1 in C: drive and to convert into binary, but while I am creating a new file stream I am getting a error "illegal characters in path".

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\image1", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        //FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\image1\farewell_pic", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
                        stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                        stream.Close();
```

How I can get rid of this error.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the file extension? Is the picture a .jpg or a .png...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to create a file you need to use different parameters.

use:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
          FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\image1", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
          FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\image1\farewell_Pic", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
          stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
          stream.Close();
  }
```